# Is there a difference between init 0 and 5 in a non-global zone?

Tags: solaris-zones

Does it make any difference if I shut down a non-global zone with `init 0` or `init 5`? Should one of them be preferred?

Answer (score 1):

i think init 0 for halt (Do NOT set initdefault to this) 
and init 5 for Shut down, power-off if hardware supports it

halt terminates all processes and shuts down the cpu.

poweroff is exactly like halt, but it also turns off the unit itself (lights and everything on a PC). It sends an ACPI command to the board, then to the PSU, to cut the power.

shutdown is like poweroff, but it also runs the shutdown scripts.

Sources:

https://serverfault.com/questions/191537/shutdown-what-is-difference-between-power-off-and-halt

http://osdir.com/ml/os.solaris.managers.summaries/2001-10/msg00027.html

Comment: since the original poster is asking this question on the Solaris Zones, `init 5` command doesn't provide him any extra benefit, as non global zone has no control of system power. It has been a while since I last dealt with Solaris zones. So I can not remember if they drop to the OK prompt or not. If they do, probably you can restart the server from this prompt, if you choose to use `init 0`. If you used `init 5`, you have to go to the global zone and give a swift kick to the machine to restart it. Take  my words with a grain of salt as my Solaris fu is stale at best